# How can i get step in my list using files and loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
alph = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
```

I need to print it using a for loop and using created before file.

```
alphabeth = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
with open('alpha.txt','w') as a:
for i in alphabeth:
    a.write(i)

with open('alpha.txt','r') as a:
t = a.read()
print(t)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what about your current code is not working? There is an indentation problem, both lines after each `with` statement require indentation, but perhaps that's merely a formatting problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('alpha.txt', 'rt') as a:
    t = a.read()
    print(t)
```

works. What's the question here?